# Azure WebJob Not Loading Local App.config

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have a console job that I'am migrating to Azure WebJobs. It runs fine on the Server it was running on before (Windows 2012 R2) but as soon as I zip it up and deploy it to WebJobs it can't see any of the settings in the local app.config for the WebJob, even more so It can't refer back to any of the application settings setup in the portal either. I've been back and forth on it but can't figure out whats truly going on.

Comment: You could go to your KUDU to check whether your app.config has published to it. I test in my site and it works fine and could you give me more details like have you load app.config in local and have get the trigger for your webjob?

Comment: If it possible, you could show me your code.

Comment: Resolved the Issue By Modifying the Runtime & in the configSection Changing the Version from 2.0.0.0 to Version 4.0.0.0

    <!--<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>